# align floated article tags evenly regardless of content - WITHOUT CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I originally wanted to do this in grid but due to reasons I have to resort to the possibility of floats...

Does the `<article>` tag work differently with floating? I have 4 blocks that need to be aligned with each other irregardless of content/title length inside them.

See what I mean:

```css
.blog-side {
    padding: 1.5em 0 1.5em;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    display: table;
}

article[class*="post-"] {
    margin: 0em 1em 1em 0em;
    display: table-cell;
}

.blog-side article {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}

.blog-side article:nth-child(even) {
    width: 48%;
    float: right;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
<section class="blog-side blog-side--2col">
                <article id="post-111" class="post-111 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-fun-quizzes tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/sed-mollitia-tenetur-dolor/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Sed mollitia tenetur dolor" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
                    <span class="cat-links"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/tag/most-popular">most popular</a></span>
                </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/sed-mollitia-tenetur-dolor/" rel="bookmark">Sed mollitia tenetur dolor</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/author2">Author</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/sed-mollitia-tenetur-dolor/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T23:21:34+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:28:27+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
<article id="post-166" class="post-166 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-fun-quizzes tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/qui-voluptatem-voluptatem-quis/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Qui voluptatem voluptatem quis" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
                    <span class="cat-links"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/tag/most-popular">most popular</a></span>
                </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/qui-voluptatem-voluptatem-quis/" rel="bookmark">io huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrf</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/author2">Author</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/qui-voluptatem-voluptatem-quis/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T22:54:11+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:28:27+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
<article id="post-128" class="post-128 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/dolores-beatae-nemo-ut-voluptate-eos/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Dolores beatae nemo ut voluptate eos" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
                    <span class="cat-links"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/tag/most-popular">most popular</a></span>
                </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/dolores-beatae-nemo-ut-voluptate-eos/" rel="bookmark">io huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrf</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/Author 1/">Author 1</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/dolores-beatae-nemo-ut-voluptate-eos/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T21:48:13+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:28:28+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
<article id="post-134" class="post-134 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-fun-quizzes tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/provident-enim-necessitatibus-excepturi-voluptatum-distinctio/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Provident enim necessitatibus excepturi voluptatum distinctio" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
            </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/provident-enim-necessitatibus-excepturi-voluptatum-distinctio/" rel="bookmark">Provident enim necessitatibus excepturi voluptatum distinctio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrf</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/author2">Author</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/provident-enim-necessitatibus-excepturi-voluptatum-distinctio/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T21:05:30+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:29:00+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
            </section>
</section>
```

(you need to expand to "full width" to see the result) but the images should always be aligned no matter how much content is in them.

I tried both inline-block and vertical-align middle like a lot of similar questions say. I also did table and table-cell (as attached) too but it didn't work.

Do article tags behave differently? DO they ignore these rules or something?

I can't anything that suggests otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

you must use `grid`. i deleted child `<section>` and added two line css code.

```css
.blog-side {
    padding: 1.5em 0 1.5em;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    display: table;
}

article[class*="post-"] {
    margin: 0em 1em 1em 0em;
    display: table-cell;
}

.blog-side article {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}

.blog-side article:nth-child(even) {
    width: 48%;
    float: right;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* i added following code only */

section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- i deleted child <section> -->

<section id="wrapper">
                <article id="post-111" class="post-111 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-fun-quizzes tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/sed-mollitia-tenetur-dolor/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Sed mollitia tenetur dolor" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
                    <span class="cat-links"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/tag/most-popular">most popular</a></span>
                </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/sed-mollitia-tenetur-dolor/" rel="bookmark">Sed mollitia tenetur dolor</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/author2">Author</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/sed-mollitia-tenetur-dolor/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T23:21:34+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:28:27+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
<article id="post-166" class="post-166 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-fun-quizzes tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/qui-voluptatem-voluptatem-quis/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Qui voluptatem voluptatem quis" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
                    <span class="cat-links"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/tag/most-popular">most popular</a></span>
                </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/qui-voluptatem-voluptatem-quis/" rel="bookmark">io huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrf</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/author2">Author</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/qui-voluptatem-voluptatem-quis/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T22:54:11+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:28:27+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
<article id="post-128" class="post-128 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/dolores-beatae-nemo-ut-voluptate-eos/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Dolores beatae nemo ut voluptate eos" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
                    <span class="cat-links"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/tag/most-popular">most popular</a></span>
                </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/dolores-beatae-nemo-ut-voluptate-eos/" rel="bookmark">io huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrfio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrf</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/Author 1/">Author 1</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/dolores-beatae-nemo-ut-voluptate-eos/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T21:48:13+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:28:28+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
<article id="post-134" class="post-134 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-book-stuff category-uncategorized tag-fun-quizzes tag-most-popular">

    <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/provident-enim-necessitatibus-excepturi-voluptatum-distinctio/" class="post-thumbnail"><img class="landscape cw-lesser thumbnail full attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="701" height="394" alt="Provident enim necessitatibus excepturi voluptatum distinctio" itemprop="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></a>
    <div class="entry-tag">
            </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/provident-enim-necessitatibus-excepturi-voluptatum-distinctio/" rel="bookmark">Provident enim necessitatibus excepturi voluptatum distinctio huhuhuhuh  dggeycgeydgyegdyeg deftdfwyjdtdxfbtyxfbetwyfdx xndtewfbdtewfd bxfeutwbfyt3fntcrf</a></h2>            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/author/author2">Author</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> <a href="http://10.241.11.85/blog/2018/11/27/provident-enim-necessitatibus-excepturi-voluptatum-distinctio/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-27T21:05:30+00:00">November 27, 2018</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-01-03T18:29:00+00:00">January 3, 2019</time></a></span>            </div>
            </header>

</article>
          
</section>
```

Comment: GAH! I should've clarified in my answer - I originally DID use grid but now have to ditch it for a few reasons